# Is the $\exists x$ in $\{f(y):\exists x\ (x,y)\in A\}$ necessary?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, article-writing

Suppose $A$ is a subset of the Cartesian product $X\times Y$, and $f$ is a function from $Y$ to some set. Is it acceptable to write $\{f(y):(x,y)\in A\}$ instead of $\{f(y):\exists x\ (x,y)\in A\}$? The logic behind the second notation seems to be to first form the set $\{y:\exists x\ (x,y)\in A\}$, and then replace each $y$ by $f(y)$. Then the first notation is justified by the following: replace each pair $(x,y)\in A$ by its second coordinate, and then replace that again by its image under $f$.

Motivation: in the theory of iterated forcing, a $\mathbb{P}*\dot{\mathbb{Q}}$-generic filter $K$ over the ground model $M$ induces a $\mathbb{P}$-generic filter $G$ over $M$ and a $\dot{\mathbb{Q}}_G$-generic filter $H$ over $M[G]$. Most sources seem to write $H:=\{\dot{q}_G:\exists p\ (p,\dot{q})\in K\}$.

Comment: I agree with you that $\{f(y):(x,y)\in A\}$ is correct, as the particular case of $g(A)=\{g(x,y):(x,y)\in A\}$ for the function $g(x,y)=f(y).$

Comment: Why not write the least-confusing version of the formula?

Comment: @GEdgar You are absolutely right, but "confusing" might be a subjective concept. Recently I actually felt the extended set-builder notation $\{f(x):\Psi(x)\}$ is quite confusing in some cases

Comment: “Acceptable” might also be a subjective concept. All I can say is, I felt no confusion with either form, and would say both forms are equally acceptable. As for your motivation, forcing is a logic context. Logicians and $\exists$ are old friends. Analysts or algebraists might have a different preference.